# how should I passing byte array buffer to writefile

Tags: c++, c, windows-ce, win32gui

I am trying to write the 16byte data to the serial port, I am having the trouble to convert the value to lpcvoid,  here is my code,

```
  unsigned char Buffer[16];
  for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
  {
    Buffer[i]=0x20+i;

        bool bwrite=WriteFile(m_PortHandle, (LPCVOID)&Buffer[0], BufferSize, &Res, NULL);
  }
```

I tried (LPCVOID)&Buffer[0] that only sends the first element of the array to the serial port, and (lpvoid)&Buffer only sends the second element of the array to the serial port.  how should pass byte array to writeFile?

Thank you,
Liang

Comment: Just `Buffer` is fine. However, you might want to fill it all before calling `WriteFile`.

Comment: I need to send the one byte at the time to the serial port. WriteFile(m_PortHandle, Buffer, 1, &Res, NULL). it can only send the first element,  I would like to send entire 16 bytes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill the buffer before writing, you need to do the writing outside your for loop, like so:

```
unsigned char Buffer[16];
  for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
  {
    Buffer[i]=0x20+i;
  }
  bool bwrite=WriteFile(m_PortHandle, (LPCVOID)&Buffer[0], BufferSize, &Res, NULL);
```

Also, you don't need `&Buffer[0]` -- `&Buffer` means the same thing, as does `Buffer` which, as Roddy pointed out below, is preferable because it works even if you replace the array with a pointer to allocated memory.

UPDATE: I see from your comments that you want to *write* the bytes out one at a time. To do that, you don't really need the buffer for anything, you can just do this: (Although I confess, I don't see why you can't write the whole buffer at once with WriteFile -- the serial port will only send out one byte at a time anyway. Maybe WriteFile() has a bug?)

```
unsigned char oneChar;
for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
{
  oneChar=0x20+i;
  WriteFile(m_PortHandle, (LPCVOID)&oneChar, 1, &Res, NULL)
}
```

Whether or not you still need the cast to LPCVOID is between you, your compiler, and your organization's coding standards. :)

Comment: As indeed does `Buffer` - and that will work even if `Buffer` is `char *`

Comment: @Roddy if you mean the array name will work without the cast, I agree it will work, but I don't know the fn prototype - he might get signed/unsigned warnings or something if the pointer type doesn't quite match, depending on on compiler flags.

Comment: @Roddy doh! I get it - sorry, need more coffee this morning. Yes, the address of an array is redundant. Updating post.

Comment: The thing is I do not need to send all 16 byte at once,  I need to send 16 byte one at the time. is there any way to do that?

Comment: tried that, looking at serial sniffer,  it looks like only second element got send over.

Answer (score 1):

It sends the first element on every loop iterator because you are telling it do so.  You need to change `&Buffer[0]` to `&Buffer[i]` (and get rid of the type-cast):

```
unsigned char Buffer[16];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    Buffer[i] = 0x20+i;

    bool bwrite = WriteFile(m_PortHandle, &Buffer[i], 1, &Res, NULL);
}
```

**Update:** If you want to send all 16 bytes at one time, not send 1 byte at a time, then move the `WriteFile()` out of the loop, and tell `WriteFile()` to write 16 bytes instead of 1 byte:

```
unsigned char Buffer[16];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    Buffer[i] = 0x20+i;
}
bool bwrite = WriteFile(m_PortHandle, Buffer, 16, &Res, NULL);
```

MOST resources that `WriteFile()` supports, whether that be a file, a serial port, etc, do not care whether you perform 16 1-byte writes or 1 16-byte write.  Only message-based communication resources care, such as a named pipe running in message mode, a UDP socket, etc.  But a serial port definitely does not care.

Comment: +1 but he already stated he wanted to send the 16 bytes at a time, 1 by 1.

Comment: Yes, and that is what the above code is doing - sending 16 bytes 1 byte at a time, just like he asked for.

Comment: I have tried that before, looking at serial sniffer, it looks like only the second element got send over the serial port

Comment: The only possible way the code I showed above would only send the second element and no other elements is if `WriteFile()` is failing with an error on every element except the second element. Otherwise, something else is going on. Either you are not indexing the Buffer correctly, or the Buffer is being modified while you are sending it, or something. Try it again, and debug your code to see what it is ACTUALLY doing.

Comment: Or maybe your serial sniffer is broken.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, I meant at one time not 1 by 1.